# A contradiction on testing with smooth functions with compact support!

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f \in C^1 [a,b]$ and for all $\phi \in C^\infty_c (a,b)$, we have
\begin{equation}
\int_{a}^{b} f(x) \phi ^\prime (x) \,dx=0. \qquad \qquad (1)
\end{equation}
This gives $f$ is a constant function. Now for any $\psi \in C^\infty _c (a,b)$, let $ \phi(x) = \int _{a}^{x} \psi  (t) \,dt$. Now from (1), we have 
\begin{equation}
\int_{a}^{b} f(x) \psi (x) \,dx=0.
\end{equation}
This gives $f=0$ in $[a,b]$, a contradiction. I know f cannot be zero. But I could not figure the mistake.

Comment: @nicomezi What assertion exactly? (1) is an assumption and, in fact, integrating by parts, gives you that $f' = 0$.

Comment: @nicomezi it is clearly stated that the equality must hold for all $\phi$, not just some $\phi$ which you would like to choose.

Comment: @abir In the second case $\phi$ does not need to have compact support.

Comment: Yes. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\phi$ doesn't necessarily have compact support or even vanish at $b$ in the second situation, so the hypothesis does not guarantee that $\int_a^b f(x) \phi'(x) dx = 0$.

Comment: Thanks for the solution.